# Why this event listener not apply to the button?

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML, and from what I understand about Event Delegation it bubbles up and the same event is applied to an element’s ancestors.

In my case clicking on the UL works and it console.logs a message, however why is this not delegated to the button and other items in the form that are above it?

```html
<div class="shopping-list">
  <form class="shopping" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="item" id="item">
    <button type="submit">+ Add Item</button>
  </form>

  <ul class="list">click me</ul>
</div>
```

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
list.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log('works');
});
```

Comment: Because you're assigning a listerer to `.list`....  PS... UL should have a LI

Comment: It's not attached to the button.

Comment: Events bubble up the document hierarchy, ie child to parent

Answer (score 3):

Events can only bubble up to parent/ancestor elements (i.e. elements that it is contained inside of). So for example, events of your `ul` can get bubbled up to its containing div, `.shopping-list`.

However for the form, your `ul` is not inside of it, it is just a sibling to the form.

Answer (score 3):

With event bubbling, an event will "bubble" up from its target *to its ancestors*, like you say - but the button is *not* an ancestor of the list. If you format your HTML properly, it'll be pretty obvious:

```
<div class="shopping-list">
  <form class="shopping" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="item" id="item">
    <button type="submit">+ Add Item</button>
  </form>

  <ul class="list">click me</ul>
</div>
```

The event dispatched to the `.list` bubbles up to the `.shopping-list`, it's parent. The button is not an ancestor, so any listeners attached to the button won't see it.

If you attach a listener to the `.shopping-list`, they'll see the event, as expected:

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
list.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log('<ul> click listener');
});

document.querySelector('.shopping-list').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('div.shopping-list click listener - delegation worked');
});
```

```html
<div class="shopping-list">
  <form class="shopping" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="item" id="item">
    <button type="submit">+ Add Item</button>
  </form>

  <ul class="list">click me</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused and hope you can help me. The point of delegation is so that I don't go to every item and add an Event Listener to them? so why add an event listener .shopping-list? Can you give an example of adding an event listener to .shopping-list please?

Comment: The snippet is just an example to show that the event is seen by a listener on the clicked element, and then, during bubbling, that it's seen by a listener on a parent element. If you just want to use a single listener on the `.shopping-list` container, feel free - but you'll need to differentiate between the different clicked elements by checking the `event.target`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the parent of your element `<ul>` it's `<div class="shopping-list">`, 
So the Event bubbling can not reach your element  `<button type="submit">+ Add Item</button>` cause `<ul class="list">click me</ul>` and `<form><input></input><button></button>` are the children of your element `<div class="shopping-list">`

So we have to understand that the event bubbling begin from the child to the parent and you can reverse this direction "event capturing" by adding true after your callback function in your listener =>

`list.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log('works');
},true)`

Finally I think that you have put your `<ul>` element into your `<form>` element :
`<div class="shopping-list">`
  `<form class="shopping" autocomplete="off">`
    `<input type="text" name="item" id="item">`
    `<button type="submit">+ Add Item</button>`
     `<ul class="list">click me</ul>`
  `</form>`
`</div>`